# What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion, design

The beta version of Tor.SE has been started and it is fastly growing up, so we have to think how the design and logo of our site will look. Please write in answers the proposals, other will vote them and we'll select the best.

Comment: Realistically, site design and logo are at the very earliest anyway between 6 months to 1 year off (and thats at the earliest). Custom design and logos come only on graduation, which is a very long process.

Comment: @AsheeshR Yeah I know that, but if we will think faster, nothing bad will happend ;) I'm sure that Tor Q&A will be a regular member of SE :)

Comment: Whatever we decide here, @Jin will make up something different (and cooler) anyway.

Comment: Anyone wanting to experiment with a website design might want to visit https://media.torproject.org/ since that's where the picture files are kept.

Comment: Suggestion:  Answer your own question with some suggestions since nobody else is doing so.